# What approaches should I use to share complex object across any class

Tags: android, global-variables, share

On example we have an app that tracks Taxi drivers, a taxi driver log  in into application and pick an order to drive for given customer.

In this case we have an Order class that represents a lot of data, it's very important to have access to this object from anywhere while still being able to modify it.

From now we can:

- pass it by putting extra data to an intent, but it's not something
  that makes code readable, in some cases it won't be a solution
- deserialize the object into json and store it into cache, we still
  need to constantly update this value which is a headache when more
  complex objects are in game, one mistake and god knows when the
  mismatch happens
- store it into class that extends Application, this
  is approach I am testing right now, but I am having doubts about this
  as when app crashes / android will release app resources randomly, I am in need to restore given object state using
  black magic with cache anyway

This is a problem that I believe is shared across many applications, like Spotify's current playing track, etc.

Are there other approaches?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a sqlite database. In this case, you can access your data anywhere from your app if you create a robust GetOrders API method yourself.

[Here is a tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47166775/5838902) of creating a database.

In this case, you will never lose any data if app exits or crashes. Also, it really makes no difference compared with caching your data in memory.